# Zend same template for different modules

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am developing a system which has multiple user levels. However most of the time the views inside each modules should be the same.

For example a user view should be 99% identical to the admin view however an admin can have some small extras like delete buttons on user posts etc.

What is the best approach to not duplicate a ton of template view files within each module?

The best solution I can think of is using the _base module and putting the view files in there and inside them do an (`if($user->isAdmin()`: extra HTML bits) and have both the user module and admin module render the base module views?

Comment: I don't know Zend, but the template engine should be able to handle _partials_ (also sometimes known as _fragments_). If you split your content up into pieces, the lightweight `if` tests in the main template file should be quite trivial. Of course, if you need to do anything more than simple boolean tests, do the logic in your controller and set variables to be tested in the template.

Comment: I was thinking of using partials, Is there a way to use a "global" partial inside multiple modules? right now if I try to render a partial it always looks for it inside my current module directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating template file(layout.phtml) in your /module/Application/View/layout/ folder, then the layout will be applied for all the views.

If you want to disable layout for some specific view, you can use like this:

```
public function yourAction() {
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ));    
    $viewModel->setTerminal(true);    
    return $viewModel;
}
```

Comment: And what if I want to use that one template file on multiple modules?

Answer (score 0):

Very first need to check if user is admin then in view you can call another view partially  having extra code like delete button using $this->partial() helper.